# Swift will not print payload from notification delegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, onesignal

I can not print the delegate from did receive remote notification.I receive the notification on my physical device but when i try to access payload nothing happen. I import `import UserNotifications` I also link the user notification library but that does not help im not sure what im during wrong. Im using one signal but that should not cause the did receive notification method not to work.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    setupViewApDelegate()
    application.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    //facebook login
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    //APIkeys().oneSignal
    let onesignalInitSettings = [kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: false]
    OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions,
                                    appId: APIkeys().oneSignal,
                                    handleNotificationAction: nil,
                                    settings: onesignalInitSettings)

    OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = OSNotificationDisplayType.notification;
    OneSignal.promptForPushNotifications(userResponse: { accepted in
        print("User accepted notifications: \(accepted)")
    })


    return true
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        print("Push notification received: \(userInfo)")
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OneSignal Not calling didReceiveRemoteNotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600138/onesignal-not-calling-didreceiveremotenotification)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like I have to retrieve the payload inside of the oneSignal closure

```
OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: APIkeys().oneSignal, handleNotificationReceived:             { (notification) in
        let payload: OSNotificationPayload? = notification?.payload


        let fullMessage: String? = payload?.body

        print("Recived no" + fullMessage!)

        print("Received Notification - \(notification?.payload.notificationID) - \(notification?.payload.title)")

    }, handleNotificationAction: nil, settings: [kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt : false, kOSSettingsKeyInAppAlerts : false])
    OneSignal.promptForPushNotifications(userResponse: { accepted in
        print("User accepted notifications: \(accepted)")
    })
    OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = OSNotificationDisplayType.notification;
```